# Why use (void)1 as a no-op in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assert, no-op

I'm reviewing a third party codebase and see this definition of an `assert` macro:

```
#define assert( x ) \
     if( !( x ) ) { \
        ThrowException( __FILE__, __LINE__ ); \
     } else \
        ((void)1)
```

What's the point in `(void)1`? How is it better than idiomatic `(void)0`?

Comment: Just a lack of imagination.  Replace with (void)42 so its obvious.

Comment: This is special: http://www.google.com/codesearch#nJHaZQ1IJ84/trunk/third_party/spidermonkey/js/src/jsdhash.c&q=%22%28void%291%22&type=cs, it uses `(void)1` and `(void)0`. Perhaps to distinguish between the two when examining preprocessed output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference between `(void)1` and `(void)0`.

Comment: @iammilind: The question was "How is [`(void)1`] better than idiomatic `(void)0`?"  I answered it.  It's not, there's no difference.

Comment: @iammilind: I'm not sure there's is any insight to give.  The asker already knows they're no-ops.

Answer (score 4):

I think it does not matter that much (and will be optimized away by the compiler). And `<cassert>` is a standard C++ header (using the standard `<assert.h>` C header) which defines a standard `assert` macro, so an application should not re-define it.